# Quotient of algebraic group by the intersection of the kernels of all characters is diagonalisable

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and let $H= \bigcap_{\chi \in X(G)} \ker{\chi} $ where $X(G)$ denotes the character group of $G$. Now it is claimed in Humphreys Linear algebraic Groups exercise  16.12 that $G / H$ is diagonalisable. I am struggling to prove this statement. What I do know is that $G/H$ is necessarily abelian as commutators will be in the kernel of an arbitrary character and therefore it would be enough to show that any element of $G/H$ is diagonalisable.

Also if I could show that $X(G/H)$ is finitely generated by $\chi_1,\dots , \chi_n $ say then $(G/H) $ is diagonalisable as I can then find an injective map  from $G/H$ to a Torus $T$ given by $\phi: G/H \mapsto T \ \phi(g)=(\chi_1(g), \dots , \chi_n(g))$. However I cannot assume the statement that the character group of any algebraic group is finitely generated as I am trying to use this statement to get to that conclusion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algebraic subgroups of an algebraic group $G$ are in particular closed subschemes of $G$ and thus they satisfy the descending chain condition.
This implies that given any collection $(H_i)_{i \in I}$ of algebraic subgroups of $G$, the intersection $H = \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i$ can already be realized as a finite intersection $\bigcap_{j = 1}^n H_{i_j}$ for some indices $i_1, \dotsc, i_n \in I$.

Applying this to your setting you find finitely many characters $\chi_1, \dotsc, \chi_n$ of $G$ such that $H = \bigcap_{j = 1}^n \ker(\chi_j)$.
Then your argument gives an injective morphism of algebraic groups $G/H \subseteq \mathbf{G}_m^n$ and as you already mentioned this shows that $G/H$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot about the fact that we have a noetherian space.

Comment: Im confused: Descending chain condition, why is this subscheme Artinian?

Comment: @AbstractNonsense Noetherian is ACC for open subsets, but DCC for closed subsets.

Comment: @LukasHeger  aah okay because its 1-dimensional? I missed that

Comment: @AbstractNonsense no, that's not it. You need to review the definition of a Noetherian topological space, it's defined as a space with the descending chain condition on closed subsets (note that for an affine scheme, closed subsets correspond to radical ideals in a inclusion-*reversing* way)